# How to retrieve a property of collection as a collection of string using Java Stream api

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of class Category which contains many attributes like code, name, description, supercategory, productlist, etc. Now I want to iterate over it and retrieve each category's code and store add it in list of string. This is how I am doing it with old school way. I want to know if this can be done in better, cleaner and efficient way with Java 8 Streams.

```
List<Category> categories = categoryService.getCategoriesForProductCode(productCode);
List<String> categoryCodes = new ArrayList<>();

if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(categories)){
     for(Category cat : categories){
        categoryCodes.add(cat.getCode);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
   categoryCodes  = categories.stream()
                  .map(category->catgory.getCode()) // .map(Category::getCode)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Hadi, to be more specific the operation `.collect(Collectors.toList());` should be changed to `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));` as the former has no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned. just wanted to mention this as the OP is doing `List<String> categoryCodes = new ArrayList<>();` in their example code snippet.